# Join LINQ queries from multiple contexts

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am trying to create a ViewModel for data that I want to display in my view.  The issue is, the data being displayed is spread across 2 databases and multiple tables within each.  I've read that you cannot join Linq queries across multiple contexts, which makes sense, and I've also read that we can't use Code-First in EF5 to use Stored Procedures....which led me to using 3 different Linq queries and attempt to combine them into 1 ViewModel...I'm just not sure how to get there.

Here's my Linq queries:

```
var csdContext = new CSDContext(CustomerCode);
var masterContext = new MasterContext();

//Only returns 1 row - which is what we want.
List<Site> sites = (from s in csdContext.Sites
                join sa in csdContext.SiteAddresses
                    on s.SiteID equals sa.SiteID
                join a in csdContext.Addresses
                    on sa.AddressID equals a.AddressID
                join spv in csdContext.SiteProductVersions
                    on s.SiteID equals spv.ProductVersionID
                where s.SiteID == id
                select s).ToList();

//List
List<States> states = (from s in masterContext.StatesTable
                    select s).ToList();
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class SiteDetailsViewModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string AlternativePhone { get; set; }
    public int ProductVersionID { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I need the following data from these tables:
**csdContext - Address**
Address
Address2
City
ZipCode

**csdContext - Sites**
OfficePhone
MobilePhone
AlternativePhone

**csdContext - SiteProductVersions**
ProductVersionID

**masterContext - States**
StateCode

Here's how the tables are joined in SQL:

```
SELECT csd_a.Address, csd_a.Address2, csd_a.City, mstr_st.StateCode, csd_a.ZipCode, csd_s.OfficePhone, csd_s.MobilePhone, 
csd_s.AlternativePhone, csd_spv.ProductVersionID
FROM CSD.dbo.Sites AS csd_s 
INNER JOIN  CSD.dbo.SiteAddress AS csd_sa ON csd_sa.SiteID = csd_s.SiteID 
INNER JOIN  CSD.dbo.Address AS csd_a ON csd_a.AddressID = csd_sa.AddressID 
INNER JOIN CSD.dbo.SiteProductVersions AS csd_spv ON csd_s.SiteID = csd_spv.SiteID 
INNER JOIN MasterDB.dbo.States AS mstr_st ON mstr_st.StateID = csd_a.StateID
```

I can't figure out how to merge these 3 results to create the ViewModel data for SiteDetailsViewModel.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What prevents you to use `join` in your first query and put there another context?

Comment: Can't join across different context with EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you materialize your queries as described in OP you can use this:

```
var query = sites.Join(
            states,
            si => si.StateID,
            st => st.StateID,
           (si, st) => new SiteDetailsViewModel
                        {
                             Address = si.Address,
                             Address2 = si.Address2,
                             City = si.City,
                             StateCode = st.StateCode,
                             ZipCode = si.ZipCode,
                             OfficePhone = si.OfficePhone,
                             MobilePhone = si.MobilePhone,
                             AlternativePhone = si.AlternativePhone,
                             ProductVersionID = siProductVersionID
                        });
```

Comment: It can't be tell, if you use code as described in OP. ToList() materialized that queries and they are not connected to context already. They are just lists in memory.

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternate solution is to create views in DB #2 of the tables in DB #1. Then you can model/map those views in EF for DB #2. You would of course still need a context for DB #1 if you need to update any of the tables. But the benefit of this solution is that you can do all of your read access on a single context and get joins at the server instead of in memory.

Answer (score -1):

So why don't you write it like this:

```
from ...
...
where s.SiteID == id
select new SiteDetailsViewModel()
{
    Address = sa.Address,
    Address2 = as.Address2,
    ..
}
```

Comment: Because I need the "StateCode" from the States table, which resides in the other context.

Comment: The question is about the "..." parts.